Training upstream model parameters with end of pipeline actuals
Existing Model
I have an existing, pre-trained, RandomForest model.  For this example, let's assume the model was trained with 3 input values like this synthetic data set:
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

# Create synthetic data
np.random.seed(42)
rf_n = 1000
model_1_choices = [0, 1]
model_2_choices = [0, 2, 5.5, 8]
input1_rf = np.random.choice(model_1_choices, size=rf_n)  # Model 1 output
input2_rf = np.random.choice(model_2_choices, size=rf_n)  # Model 2 output
input3_rf = np.random.randint(0, 6, size=rf_n)  # Model 3 output
X_rf = np.column_stack((input1_rf, input2_rf, input3_rf))
y_rf = input1_rf * 0.5 + input2_rf * 0.3 + input3_rf * 0.2 + np.random.normal(0, 0.05, rf_n)
y_rf = np.clip(y_rf, 0, 5)

# Train Random Forest model
rf_model = RandomForestRegressor()
rf_model.fit(X_rf, y_rf)

New Dataset Implications
Now, I have a different data set where we have similar information to the existing model inputs, but there are more input columns.  Think of it like more granular level data, but all of the inputs are binary (0/1).  Also, in this 2nd data set, the actuals I have don't cover the same range of values the original random forest was trained on.  The original was trained on output values from 0 to 5 and this 2nd data set only has output values from 3 to 5 (similar to a class imbalance issue).  Due to this, I want to retain the existing, trusted, trained RandomForest model and create/train models that map the new data set inputs into the existing RandomForest inputs.  Something like this:
Output
  ^
  |
RandomForest
  ^
  |
  ⊢ Model1
  ⊢ Model2
  ⊢ Model3

Here's some synthetic data to represent the 2nd data set binary inputs and some fake output data.  Let's assume that the 1st 3 columns map to the first model, 2nd 3 to the 2nd model, and so on.
# Create synthetic binary data
np.random.seed(42)
pipeline_n = 1000
X_pipeline = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(pipeline_n, 9))

# Create a synthetic target that includes dependencies on columns 6, 7, and 8
y_pipeline = (X_pipeline[:, 0] * 0.4 + X_pipeline[:, 1] * 0.3 + X_pipeline[:, 2] * 0.2 +
              X_pipeline[:, 3] * 0.1 + X_pipeline[:, 4] * 0.05 + X_pipeline[:, 5] * 0.05 +
              X_pipeline[:, 6] * 0.15 + X_pipeline[:, 7] * 0.1 + X_pipeline[:, 8] * 0.05 +
              np.random.normal(0, 0.05, pipeline_n))
y_pipeline = np.clip(y_pipeline, 3, 5)

Finally, the Question
Is there a way for me to create something like a pipeline where I can train the underlying 3 models, while locking the RandomForest model and it's parameters in place?  I've looked into using scikit-learn pipelines, but I haven't found an example like this were the model(s) being trained are not the final step in the pipeline.  It's also a bit tricky because if I build a CustomTransformer for the 3 models, the fit method gets really tricky/messy.  The standard fit would look something like this:
def fit(self, X, y=None):
    # Fit each model using the entire dataset and target
    self.model_1.fit(X[:, :3], y)
    self.model_2.fit(X[:, 3:6], y)
    self.model_3.fit(X[:, 6:], y)
    return self

That wouldn't work because the y that gets passed is the final output, which is not what we would want in this situation.  What I'm asking about feels a lot like what happens during back-propagation when a neural network trains.  Is what I'm asking for possible?  If so, how would I do it?
